# convert curl to python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to convert the following curl request to a python requests (using the Requests)

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "modelId=CommunitySentiment" -F "document=the presentation was great and I learned a lot"  https://api.einstein.ai/v2/language/sentiment
```

the response would be a json
{"probabilities": [{
            "label": "positive",
            "probability": 0.8673582
        },
        {
            "label": "negative",
            "probability": 0.1316828
        },
        {
            "label": "neutral",
            "probability": 0.0009590242
        }
    ]
}

My python script is as follows, however, it returns a 400 bad request.

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer 1ca35fd8454f74ff5496614a858bfd4c80bd196b','Cache-Control': 'no-cache','Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}

files = json.dumps({'modelId':'CommunitySentiment','document': 'the presentation was great and I learned a lot'})

r = requests.post('https://api.einstein.ai/v2/language/sentiment', headers=headers, data=files, verify=False)
```

I feel I'm missing something or converting something wrong...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `curl -F` doesn't JSON-encode the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-part form data can be sent using `files` argument, e.g. compare:

```
$ curl -F "document=the presentation was great and I learned a lot" -F "modelId=CommunitySentiment" http://httpbin.org/post
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "document": "the presentation was great and I learned a lot", 
    "modelId": "CommunitySentiment"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Content-Length": "303", 
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------11650e244656399f", 
    "Expect": "100-continue", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.55.1"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "X.X.X.X", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Python requests:

```
In []:
import requests

files = {
    'modelId': (None, 'CommunitySentiment'),
    'document': (None, 'the presentation was great and I learned a lot')
}

requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', files=files).json()

Out []:
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "document": "the presentation was great and I learned a lot", 
    "modelId": "CommunitySentiment"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Content-Length": "279", 
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=7cb959d7e990471c90c0bce7b92ab697", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.18.4"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "24.13.37.157", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

So your example would be:

```
In []:
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <TOKEN>',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
}
files = {
    'modelId': (None, 'CommunitySentiment'),
    'document': (None, 'the presentation was great and I learned a lot')
}
requests.post('https://api.einstein.ai/v2/language/sentiment', headers=headers, files=files, verify=False).json()

Out[]:
{'object': 'predictresponse',
 'probabilities': [{'label': 'positive', 'probability': 0.8673582},
  {'label': 'negative', 'probability': 0.1316828},
  {'label': 'neutral', 'probability': 0.0009590242}]}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer and it works perfectly!  But I still have a question about                 files = {
    'modelId': (None, 'CommunitySentiment'),
    'document': (None, 'the presentation was great and I learned a lot')
}. Why should I add the 'None' in both the elements?

Comment: The first value would be for the `filename`, which is unnecessary in a `multipart/form-data`, but useful when sending actual files.

Answer (score 10):

Use [curlconverter.com](https://curlconverter.com/), it converts your command like this:

[image: a screen shot of curlconverter.com, the curl command in the question is in a textbox with the corresponding Python+Requests code below it]

Answer (score 0):

You're converting this JSON object to a string using the `json.dumps()` function:

```
files = json.dumps({'modelId':'CommunitySentiment','document': 'the presentation was great and I learned a lot'})
```

Requests.post() wants a dict, not a string. Replace the previous line with:

```
files = {'modelId':'CommunitySentiment','document': 'the presentation was great and I learned a lot'}
```